# Mongodb TypeError: class heritage events_1.EventEmitter is not an object or null

Tags: typescript, mongodb, vuejs3, vite

I'm seeing an issue from the mongodb@5.8.1 npm dependency. I am trying to use mongodb in my Vue.js + Vite + Typescript app but my app crashes and cannot load due to the following error coming from mongodb. I'm not sure why it's trying to resolve events to `events_1`, I suspect that might be related to this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: class heritage events_1.EventEmitter is not an object or null
    js mongo_types.ts:402
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js abstract_cursor.ts:16
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js aggregation_cursor.ts:11
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js collection.ts:6
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js change_stream.ts:4
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js index.ts:4
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    <anonymous> mongodb.js:28990
mongo_types.ts:402
```

Steps to recreate:

1. `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app --template vue-ts`
2. `npm install mongodb`
3. Add the following lines into `main.ts`

```
import { MongoClient } from mongodb
const client = new MongoClient("")
```

4. `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src/main.ts` in the template is dedicated to run on `browser` env while the `mongodb` is a package which is designed to run on server (`node` in this case) only.

```
// src/entry-server.ts

// your server code goes here
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"

const client = new MongoClient("...")
```

As result of that, you need to import this package to `entry-server` which runs on server only, and how to create 2 separate endpoints for `server` and `client` respectively you can follow this [official document](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#setting-up-the-dev-server)

BTW, here are a few starter repos with server side setup that you can more and follow:

- https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/tree/main/playground/ssr-vue
- https://github.com/vok123/vue3-ts-vite-ssr-starter

Comment: Ah I see. I wanted to use mongodb change streams to have the client app update a vue component when a collection is updated, but if I have to run mongodb in a server then that defeats the purpose. So then is my only option to use websockets?

Comment: Also mongodb's documentation did not list this important piece of information, very disappointed in mongodb for that

Comment: Actually I just discovered about server-sent events using EventSource, will see if this is a viable option.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource